# How to customise workbox build with path to assets for precashing

Tags: service-worker, create-react-app, workbox

I'm setting a custom config for generating a service Worker.
I 'm using the injectManifest. The problem is that my assets are deployed to s3 bucket with different domain than app runs.

I have read all the dos, but havenn't found any config option for that.

```
const buildSW = () => {
    // This will return a Promise
    return workboxBuild
        .injectManifest({
            swSrc: 'src/sw-template.js',
            swDest: 'build/sw.js', // this will be created in the build step
            globDirectory: 'build',
            globPatterns: ['**\/*.{js, html}'],
        })
        .then(({ count, size, warnings }) => {
            // Optionally, log any warnings and details.
            warnings.forEach(console.warn);
            console.log(`${count} files will be precached, totaling ${size} bytes.`);
        });
};
buildSW();
```

I receive config like :

```
    "url": "static/js/runtime~main.ccae3505.js",
    "revision": "51731239672d142923190a6cfb73ce8b"
  },
```

but would like something like

````
    "url": "https://myCustomDomain.com/static/js/runtime~main.ccae3505.js",
    "revision": "51731239672d142923190a6cfb73ce8b"
  },```
````

Answer (score 0):

I found it - hope it will be useful for someone:
`manifestTransforms` can do the trick